# wlan0 keeps coming up

Tags: pi-3, wifi, archlinux

wlan0 gets disabled at startup. I've checked it and it is down right after startup.

When I check 15 min later, the wlan0 interface is back up again. Is this normal behavior? If not, how can I check what process brings this back up?

I don't want to write a script that checks every second if wlan0 is running, but I'll have to if this problem is not solved.

I'm running Arch btw.

Comment: *wlan0 gets disabled at startup* ... how? perhaps you're doing this wrong

Comment: This question is meaningless. `arch` has no standard default networking so unless you explain what you installed, and how you configured it is unanswerable.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. I've installed Armv7 with extra/networkmanager. I made a startup script that takes wlan0 down.

Comment: Problem solved: https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/5oo4m8/disabling_ethernet_by_default_on_networkmanager/